# How do you specify a really large character in UIButton?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uibutton, font-size

I have a series of buttons that have suit symbols on them.  Currently I provide these suit symbols as bitmaps.  In preparation for iPhone 4 I'd like to use text instead.  However Interface Builder rescales the button to account for whitespace underneath the symbol so I can't get the image to fill the button completely.

Any hints on getting Interface Builder to behave?

Answer (score 0):

Use transparent suit symbols that are all the same size such as [Crystal Clear icons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Clear).

Comment: Wouldn't that mean I have to use a bitmap?  I'm trying to use text so I don't have to supply two bitmaps to support the larger display sizes.